# django template engine variable in URL (RSS)

Tags: django, url, rss, template-engine, rss-reader

I'm writing a RSS feed in django. I give the item tag a link tag with the link to the original product. my URL looks like `http://localhost:8000//nieuws_helpdesk.html?year={{ item.publish_date_start|date:"Y" }}&month={{ item.publish_date_start|date:"m" }}`

For some reason i dies completely when i use the &. It just stops their.
When i only use year or only month is does work btw.

Does anybody know how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand: `&` should be `&amp;`.